# Soccer league standings feature in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I would like to be able to display the standings of different games in a soccer league using Drupal.

I have a created a content type that lists the two teams that are playing against each other and their scores and i have tried to use the views to try to display the standings but i don't get the desired results.

My content type has the following configuration

```
Team name = team A
Team name = team B
score team A = 2
Score team B = 3
Game date = 12/12/2014
```

This is what i would like to achieve

```
Ranking | Team | Points | Goals difference | Goals scored | Goals against
1         A      3        4                  4              0
2         B      3        3                  3              0 
3         C      3        1                  2              1
4         D      3        1                  1              0
5         E      3        1                  1              0
6         F      1        0                  2              2 
7         G      1        0                  0              0
```

Can some one help ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how can i create a soccer league standig feature in drupal

Comment: your question is too general. many ways.